# Increase Table Width to Fit Three Tables on Slide

Tags: tables

I am currently trying to fit three tables on one slide, while I understand this may not be recommended, I figured I would like to at least be able to see the slide and how it looks before ruling it out.

I have the below code

```
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\tiny}
\begin{frame}
\tiny
\begin{table}{$\dot{x}$}
\centering
\tiny
\begin{tabular}
\toprule
\tiny
\textit{N} & \thead{Method\\ One} & \thead{Method Two\\ + Extra} &
\thead{Method Three\\ Some Words} & \thead{Method Four\\ Some Words\\ + Extra} & \thead{Method Five} & \thead{Method\\ Six} & Final\\
\midrule
10^2 & 6.87e-07 & 7.11e-16 & 3.56e-01 & 1.19e+01 & 6.64e+00 & 9.43e-08 & 4.27e+01\\
10^{2.5} & 1.55e-13 & 2.26e-16 & 1.75e-09 & 5.53e-14 & 7.24e+01 & 1.10e+02 & 5.13e+01\\
10^3 & 1.67e-13 & 1.95e-15 & 2.21e-12 & 1.95e-15 & 9.38e-05 & 1.95e-15 & 4.75e+01\\
10^{3.5} & 2.11e-16 & 2.11e-16 & 1.42e-12 & 2.11e-16 & 1.79e-02 & 8.31e-12 & 1.38e-14\\
10^4 & 6.05e-14 & 1.58e-18 & 1.63e-12 & 1.58e-18 & 1.07e-01 & 4.68e-13 & 7.23e+00\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}{$\dot{y}$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccccccc}
\toprule
\textit{N} & \thead{Method\\ One} & \thead{Method Two\\ + Extra} &
\thead{Method Three\\ Some Words} & \thead{Method Four\\ Some Words\\ + Extra} & \thead{Method Five} & \thead{Method\\ Six} & Final\\
\midrule
10^2 & 5.46e+00 & 1.75e-13 & 1.18e+01 & 5.54e+00 & 6.94e+00 & 5.54e+00 & 5.54e+00\\
10^{2.5} & 1.16e-06 & 4.48e-13 & 2.69e+01 & 3.58e-06 & 4.41e+01 & 3.64e+01 & 3.64e+01\\
10^3 & 7.19e-13 & 1.41e-14 & 3.36e+00 & 1.15e-07 & 7.02e+01 & 5.74e-07 & 2.30e+01\\
10^{3.5} & 8.26e-13 & 2.22e-14 & 7.88e-06 & 7.01e-14 & 9.10e-01 & 7.03e-10 & 7.09e+00\\
10^4 & 4.04e-12 & 1.63e-17 & 3.45e-03 & 6.62e-13 & 2.61e+00 & 3.25e-11 & 1.43e-14\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}{$\dot{z}$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccccccc}
\toprule
\textit{N} & \thead{Method\\ One} & \thead{Method Two\\ + Extra} &
\thead{Method Three\\ Some Words} & \thead{Method Four\\ Some Words\\ + Extra} & \thead{Method Five} & \thead{Method\\ Six} & Final\\
\midrule
10^2 & 4.72e-08 & 7.35e-14 & 4.34e+01 & 4.36e+01 & 3.64e+00 & 5.01e+01 & 4.36e+01\\
10^2.5 & 5.44e-13 & 8.28e-14 & 1.76e+01 & 1.16e+02 & 6.27e+00 & 6.14e+01 & 1.16e+02\\
10^3 & 3.24e-14 & 8.01e-14 & 3.14e-09 & 8.01e-14 & 9.86e-05 & 8.01e-14 & 1.16e+02\\
10^{3.5} & 1.68e-13 & 8.94e-14 & 6.60e-12 & 8.94e-14 & 4.93e-05 & 1.68e-13 & 7.19e+01\\
10^4 & 5.21e-14 & 7.57e-14 & 3.42e-12 & 7.57e-14 & 3.26e-03 & 7.57e-14 & 1.41e-14\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The column names here resemble my real data, and I was hoping to be able to place them over two lines in the column headers. Essentially, I would like to find a way to put these three tables on the same slide. If that means all three on top of each other, that could work, or all three next to each other as well. I've read recommendations from other posts that it could be good to remove some columns, which I would consider doing but was hoping to generally learn how to fit these tables on the same slide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Also, your tabularx environment is missing its column specifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already suspected, I would not recomment squeezing that many numbers onto a single slide in a presentation. Here is nevertheless a way to achive what you asked for. In order to save space, I used a single table instead of three different tables and in order to improve the alignment of the numbers, I added the `siunitx` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\tiny}
\begin{frame}{frame title}
\begin{table}
\tiny \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}}, retain-explicit-plus, retain-zero-exponent}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{$}l<{$}*{7}{S[table-format=1.2e-1]}@{}}
\toprule
\textit{N} & {\thead{Method\\ One}} & {\thead{Method Two\\ + Extra}} &
{\thead{Method Three\\ Some Words}} & {\thead{Method Four\\ Some Words\\ + Extra}} & {\thead{Method\\ Five}} & {\thead{Method\\ Six}} & {\thead{Final}}\\
\midrule
\dot{x} \\
10^2 & 6.87e-07 & 7.11e-16 & 3.56e-01 & 1.19e+01 & 6.64e+00 & 9.43e-08 & 4.27e+01\\
10^{2.5} & 1.55e-13 & 2.26e-16 & 1.75e-09 & 5.53e-14 & 7.24e+01 & 1.10e+02 & 5.13e+01\\
10^3 & 1.67e-13 & 1.95e-15 & 2.21e-12 & 1.95e-15 & 9.38e-05 & 1.95e-15 & 4.75e+01\\
10^{3.5} & 2.11e-16 & 2.11e-16 & 1.42e-12 & 2.11e-16 & 1.79e-02 & 8.31e-12 & 1.38e-14\\
10^4 & 6.05e-14 & 1.58e-18 & 1.63e-12 & 1.58e-18 & 1.07e-01 & 4.68e-13 & 7.23e+00\\
\midrule
\dot{y}\\
10^2 & 5.46e+00 & 1.75e-13 & 1.18e+01 & 5.54e+00 & 6.94e+00 & 5.54e+00 & 5.54e+00\\
10^{2.5} & 1.16e-06 & 4.48e-13 & 2.69e+01 & 3.58e-06 & 4.41e+01 & 3.64e+01 & 3.64e+01\\
10^3 & 7.19e-13 & 1.41e-14 & 3.36e+00 & 1.15e-07 & 7.02e+01 & 5.74e-07 & 2.30e+01\\
10^{3.5} & 8.26e-13 & 2.22e-14 & 7.88e-06 & 7.01e-14 & 9.10e-01 & 7.03e-10 & 7.09e+00\\
10^4 & 4.04e-12 & 1.63e-17 & 3.45e-03 & 6.62e-13 & 2.61e+00 & 3.25e-11 & 1.43e-14\\
\midrule
\dot{z} \\
10^2 & 4.72e-08 & 7.35e-14 & 4.34e+01 & 4.36e+01 & 3.64e+00 & 5.01e+01 & 4.36e+01\\
10^{2.5} & 5.44e-13 & 8.28e-14 & 1.76e+01 & 1.16e+02 & 6.27e+00 & 6.14e+01 & 1.16e+02\\
10^3 & 3.24e-14 & 8.01e-14 & 3.14e-09 & 8.01e-14 & 9.86e-05 & 8.01e-14 & 1.16e+02\\
10^{3.5} & 1.68e-13 & 8.94e-14 & 6.60e-12 & 8.94e-14 & 4.93e-05 & 1.68e-13 & 7.19e+01\\
10^4 & 5.21e-14 & 7.57e-14 & 3.42e-12 & 7.57e-14 & 3.26e-03 & 7.57e-14 & 1.41e-14\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```